# A user wants to subscribe to a product using HUAWEI IAP, but the payment page is inaccessible

Tags: in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

Public key and AGC configurations are correct, but when a user tries subscribing to a product, error code -1 is returned, and the payment page fails to be displayed.

Comment: Provide more information like logcat or anything helpful that might help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, check whether the log contains
"errorCode:6". The error code returned to the SDK layer is -1, indicating that the order fails to be created.

```html
public class OrderStatusCode {
    public static final int ORDER_STATE_SUCCESS = 0;
    public static final int ORDER_STATE_FAILED = -1;
}
```

Check whether the order creation failure is caused by the server. If not, check whether the product created in the PMS contains invalid fields and whether the product is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you didn't set IAP function yet, you might have missed this step.[image: Before setting IAP function for your app]

In this you can see "IAP function has not been set yet!" and a settings button. Click the settings button to set IAP function for your app.

If you finished it your page will be like this[image: After setting IAP function for your app]

Now all you have to do is wait for some time around 5 or 10 minutes and IAP can purchased in you app in mobile.